# How to force kill any running mysql query?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-rds

A mysql query is running from last 24 hours and when we are trying to kill that query, it is saying you are not the owner of the query so you can't kill this query.

Do we know how to kill any running query?

Comment: *"Do we know how to kill any running query?"* The answer is more or less *' The ability to kill threads and statements depends on the CONNECTION_ADMIN and SUPER privileges:

    Without CONNECTION_ADMIN or SUPER, you can kill only your own threads and statements.

    With CONNECTION_ADMIN or SUPER, you can kill all threads and statements "* [KILL Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/kill.html)

Comment: I have the admin rights but not able to kill it using the kill query button from MySQLWorkBench.

Comment: *"I have the admin rights but not able to kill it using the kill query button from MySQLWorkBench. "* i doubt that MySQL does not give invalid error messages if MySQL says that you not the owner your simply not the owner.. Pretty sure this is a human error.. 1) your current MySQL user does not have anny of the CONNECTION_ADMIN and SUPER privileges 2) You are using the incorrect account .. Meaning run `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` and post the results then we can see and to verify you indeed have a running super useraccount.

Comment: Also which MySQL version are you using? `SELECT VERSION()` as [MySQL 8.0](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_parse.cc#L6350) included some extra privilege checks in the KILL syntax vs [MySQL 5(.7)](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/sql_parse.cc#L6429) , which also might be your problem here..

Answer (score 1):

run below query for show all running query

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

it will show all query in execution.
e.g

```
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| 253 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | show PROCESSLIST |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
```

after that run below query

```
kill 253;
```

will kill that query

Comment: I find this article very useful. They have mentioned to kill any running processes. 
https://eldfrog.com/kill-mysql-long-running-query-on-aws-rds/